# Unwanted UITableView Animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, storyboard

I have a simple UIViewController_A in a Storyboard with a button on it.  The button modal segues (page curl) to UIViewController_B which has a container view.  The container view then embeds UITableViewController_A.  The table displays 1 section containing 3 custom static cells.  Each cell has a label on the left and a switch on the right.

When I click on the button, the table is properly displayed where I want it but the cells content, labels and switches, are animated to their positions.

How can I disable this animation?  I suspect it is the embedded tableview getting animated while being resized, but am not sure.

I put a simple demo of the problem on github : https://github.com/droussel/UnwantedAnimation

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about storyboard concept.But I suspect you are starting some animation in button action to have an animation like paging.If so, then just commit(end) your animation after achieved what you want.

```
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: There is no code at all in there, everything is linked up within the storyboard. It seems to be some bug or default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that only the middle cell animates in. If I increase the cells to 5, the middle 3 animate. This only happens with the partial curl animation -- this looks like a bug in the auto layout system to me. If you turn off auto layout, the problem goes away.

Comment: Yup, really strange indeed. Unfortunately, I can't turn off autolayout for this storyboard. I may just have to live with it but I'll wait to see if someone comes up with a solution.

Comment: @droussel, yeah this is strange. It seems  to be a problem with square edged cells. If you use a plain table, then all the cells (which are square edged) animate, and in the grouped table, only the middle, non-rounded, cells animate.

Comment: I opened a radar and attached the simple project. We'll see what comes out of it!

Answer (score 0):

In Storyboard segue to that scene/view, open the Attributes inspector, and uncheck ANIMATES. Turns out there is a bug with iOS8 with Partial Curl/Animates.

Hope that helps!